# JavaScript background color change function does not interact with the html button

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my first time using StackOverflow, so I still don't know how to use the code snippets properly.

I am still a beginner into programming and chose to start with the front-end side, i've done an orange background with "this is the red heading" written in red, it worked.

however, I'm trying to make a button that when it's clicked, only the background color changes from orange to yellow, but the button doesn't do anything at all.

here's the code("estilo" is the name of the CSS file and "responsividade" is the name of the JS file):

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById("redhead").style.backgroundColor = "yellowbg";
}
```

```css
#redhead {
  background-color: orange;
  color: red;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#yellowbg {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">

    <script src="responsividade.js"></script>

    <h1 id="redhead">this is the red heading</h1>


    <button type="button" onclick="changeColor()">Click Here</button>

  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_ - _"does not work"_ is not a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: `document.getElementById("redhead").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";` you are trying to assign a css class name to the backgroun color property.

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById("redhead").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

```css
#redhead {
  background-color: orange;
  color: red;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#yellowbg {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> </head>

  <body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">

    <script src="responsividade.js"></script>

    <h1 id="redhead">this is the red heading</h1>


    <button type="button" onclick="changeColor()">Click Here</button>

  </body>


</html>
```

Comment: That's still invalid markup. And that's just a typo and you should vote to close as such.

Comment: @Andreas While there are multiple issues that should also be addressed, I think the assumption that a CSS selector can be assigned to a style in JS like that is more than a typo and is worth clarifying in an answer.

Comment: @DBS How does _"you assign a class to a property"_, _"that's invalid markup"_ help future readers of that question? It only helps OP: _"While similar questions may be on-topic here, **this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.**"_

Answer (score 0):

1. You have written your code in the `head` tag.
2. In background-color value given as `yellowbg`.

```js
function changeColor() {
    document.getElementById("redhead").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

```css
#redhead {
    background-color: orange;
    color: red;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

#yellowbg {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">

    <script src="responsividade.js"></script>

    <h1 id="redhead">this is the red heading</h1>


    <button type="button" onclick="changeColor()">Click Here</button>

</body>

</html>
```

`#yellowbg` ruleset all properties are there in `#readhead` ruleset except background-color so in js, you can just update background color only.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change color try `document.getElementById("redhead").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";`

or if you want to set another id try
`document.getElementById("redhead").setAttribute('id', 'yellowbg');`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const colorChanger = {
  'eq'        : 0,
  'change'    : function(targetID, colorCircles) {
    document.getElementById(targetID).style.backgroundColor = colorCircles[this.eq];
    this.eq = (this.eq === colorCircles.length-1) ? 0:this.eq += 1;
  }
}
```

```css
#test{
  border  :1px solid #000;
  width   :100px;
  height  :100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<button onclick="colorChanger.change('test', ['red','yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'])">Change Color</button>

<!--
colorChanger.change('test', ['red','yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']
------------------------------------------------------
>target is something with id 'test'
>and background color of target ID will be change using this circles ['red','yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Js function you need to a background color as you trying to do.

```
document.getElementById("redhead").style.backgroundColor = "yellowbg";
```

"yellowbg" is not a color but an Id.

So you need to change that to

```
 document.getElementById("redhead").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

You can add css property to a class of an element and with js change the class name to add different property to that element.

```
document.getElementById("redhead").className = "newClass";
```